# How to show tqdm progress bar only after a certain time?

Tags: python-3.x, tqdm

I am using `tqdm` to show progress in my method:

```
def crunch(u):
    for i in tqdm(u):
        do_work(i)
```

The problem is when I call this method a lot, on many different `u` and I don't know ahead of time how big `u` will be. Some `u` are very small and the progress bar is not needed. I end up with many progress bars cluttering up my console output. I would like the `tqdm` bar to start displaying only if the loop has been running for more than 1 sec, for example. For loops that complete in less than a second, `tqdm` should not print any progress at all.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#__init__) of `tqdm.tqdm(...)`, there is an argument `delay` specifically for this purpose:

> - delay: float, optional
>
>   Don't display until [default: 0] seconds have elapsed.

So, in your case, you can do

```py
def crunch(u):
    for i in tqdm(u, delay=1):
        do_work(i)
```

which will have `tqdm` to start display only if the loop has been running for more than 1 sec.